# How to open a new browser and display a pdf but using a POST method?

Tags: .net, html, rest, wcf-rest

I've got a web service that requires data to be posted via a POST method using JSON format in order to request a specific document (.pdf).

The document will need to be stream down and opened in the browser but I would like to open a new browser to display the document?

Can this be achieved without using a query string and GET method? To recap, is there a way to open a new browser and post data to the URL the same way you would if you just clicked on a button on a page?

I'm using JQuery to post my data but a solution in either HTML5 or ASP.NET would be good.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this, so my work-around was to create a table with encrypted data in it and when a user clicked one of the row, it launched a new browser with a query string using the relevant encrypted data.

The minute the new browser is launched, it decrypts the encrypted query strings and then calls my web service using a POST method.

I don't know if this is an acceptable method, but it will have to do I guess.

Thanks.

T.